# Javascript question. How to select multiple nodes by ID, where ID starts with the same word?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, getelementbyid

Ok, my first question on SO ever.
So I have the following html:

```html
<div class="tables">
  <section id="table__1">
  </section>
  <section id="table__2">
  </section>
  <section id="table__3">
  </section>
</div>
```

I know I can select those sections using `getElementByID`, or using `querySelector('#ID');`.
But how can all those sections can be selected just by the first part of the IDs that is the same across all of them.
I tried `document.querySelectorAll("section[id^="table__"]")`, which did not work.
Did I messed the syntax up, or this wont work regardless? If so, is there a way to make such a selection?

Comment: First, try single quotes around the partial ID. Second, you have the word `tables` (plural) in your code example, but your markup has the word `table` (singular). Example: `document.querySelectorAll("section[id^='table__']")`

Comment: try this '[id^=table__]'

Comment: As an aside, I recommend you rethink your HTML approach, if you have control over that. In most cases, it would be better if you selected all children by other criteria, such as class, tagname, or "data-" attribute. IDs should be used for singular identification, and are not an ideal construct for partial matching selection.

Answer (score 0):

You should use single quotes for your selector because you can't use double quotes inside of double quotes. Also your selector should be `table__` not `tables__`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('section[id^="table__"]')
```

https://jsbin.com/ravecekiki/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: That plural was a typo, but that fact about no double quotes inside double quotes blew my mind! I've been digging into coding and JS specifically for the last 6 months now, and I never stumbled upon this thing. Thank you!   PS. Turns out I cant upvote until I reach some sorta level.

Comment: No worries. If you do need to use double quotes inside of double quotes for some reason, it is possible by escaping the inner double quotes with a \ character like this `document.querySelectorAll("section[id^=\"table__\"]")`